# php : retrieve custom random number in php

Tags: php

The following code generates random number from 1 to 10

```
$ran = rand(1,10);
```

What if i want random numbers from my custom values.that is **(1,3,6,7,9)**

for example i need to generate any one number from the group (1,3,6,7,9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that as following,

```
<?PHP

$numbers = array(1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 4 => 4, 5 => 5, 6 => 6);
$random_key = array_rand($numbers, 1);
print $random_key;

?>
```

Comment: The keys here are reluctant. using `$numbers[array_rand($numbers)]` is enough.

Comment: WAIT..i want this value (1,3,6,7,9) ,,,1 => 5, 2 => 9, 3 => 6, 4 => 9, 5 => 11, 6 => 4); when i do like that i get 1,2,3,4,5, only

Comment: @PankajjKumar: It's the keys which matter in this example.

Answer (score 1):

You want [**`array_rand()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

or you could **[`shuffle()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)** and always just reference `$array[0]` which would also be "random"

Comment: You should try and provide an example

Comment: I'd rather have anyone searching or the OP to learn to utilize the PHP manual than just get specific examples on SO. Understanding the direct source with examples is more important than providing a specific example to the OP's case, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You need `array_rand` function for that . the Parameters are `array_rand ( array $input [, int $num_req = 1 ] )` . For your purpose , use it as `$var_rand = array_rand($arr);` as you want only 1 random number generated . For more help, refer to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php.)

Also , for future questions , post your php version too. Some functions are not available in older versions . This one is available , though.